# Document Locked for Editing

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I am using Excel to run a mail merge, and everything works great "EXCEPT"...

Once the docs are created, they are also locked for editing. If I try to delete one I get a pop-up stating that the action can't be completed because the document is open in "Word (Desktop)". If I try to open it or anything else, I can only open as a read only copy.
I have been asking around everywhere and no one seems to know as no one has responded!

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
  Private Sub cmdGenerateAR_Click()
  Dim bCreatedWordInstance As Boolean
  Dim objWord As Object
  Dim objMMMD As Object
  Dim SMName As String
  Dim cDir As String
  Dim r As Long
  Dim ThisFileName As String
     Set ws1 = Sheets("Release LettersAR")
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     LastRow = Sheets("Release LettersAR").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      r = 2      
     SMName = Sheets("Release LettersAR").Cells(r, 2).Value

     ' Setup filenames        
     Const WTempName = "MailMergeMainDocumentAR.docx" 'This is the Word Templates name, Change as req'd
     Dim NewFileName As String

     ' Setup directories
     cDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" 'Change if appropriate
     ThisFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name

     On Error Resume Next
     ' Create a Word Application instance
     bCreatedWordInstance = False
     Set objWord = New Word.Application
     If objWord Is Nothing Then
        Err.Clear
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        bCreatedWordInstance = True
     End If

     If objWord Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not start Word"
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub
     End If

       ' Let Word trap the errors
       On Error GoTo 0
       ' Set to True if you want to see the Word Doc flash past during construction
       objWord.Visible = True
       'Open Word Template
       Set objMMMD = objWord.Documents.Open(cDir + "\" + WTempName)
       objMMMD.Activate         

       'Merge the data
       For r = 2 To LastRow
         While (Sheets("Release LettersAR").Cells(r, 20).Value > "") And (r < (LastRow + 1))    
            With objMMMD
              .MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=cDir + "\" + ThisFileName, sqlstatement:="SELECT * FROM `Release LettersAR$`" ' Set this as required
               With objMMMD.MailMerge
                   .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                   .SuppressBlankLines = True
                   With .DataSource
                        .FirstRecord = r - 1
                        .LastRecord = r - 1
                        .ActiveRecord = r - 1            
                   End With
                   .Execute Pause:=False
                End With
            End With

           On Error Resume Next ' Save new file
           NewFileName = SMName & "- USAR Release Letter -" & Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy") & ".docx" '  'This is the New Word Document File Name
           objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs cDir + "\Completed Files\" + NewFileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
           'objWord.ActiveDocument.PrintOut
           ' Close the Mail Merge Main Document
           objMMMD.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
           Set objMMMD = Nothing
           'Close the New Mail Merged Document
           If bCreatedWordInstance = False Then
              If Not (objWord Is Nothing) Then
                 objWord.Close (False)
                 Set objWord = Nothing
            End If        
         End If

         Sheets("Release LettersAR").Rows(, r).ClearContents
      Wend     
    Next r

    objWord.Quit
    Word.Application.Quit
    Set objMMMD = Nothing: Set objWord = Nothing

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    Do Until objWord Is Nothing
        Debug.Print objWord
        objWord.Quit False
        'start from scratch
        Set objWord = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MsgBox "USAR Letters have been successfully created!", vbOKOnly, "NOTICE"

End Sub
```

Comment: What I am now trying to accomplish is making it so that if they have not entered the additional data, the merge process will simply skip that line and move to the next (code is included but will not break the While Loop I am using (UGH!).
Anyway...I have edited my original post with the new code as it is currently. Hope I made the right changes...

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, currently, but I can say that the `If` block starting with `If bCreatedWordInstance = False Then` is in the wrong place. This should not be *in* the loop. Also, this line `objWord.Close (False)` is incorrect - the Word.Application cannot be closed. Get rid of `On Error Resume Next ` so that you can see where the errors are occurring. If you hide the errors there' s no chance of fixing the code! And this loop ` Do Until objWord Is Nothing` makes absolutely NO sense.

Comment: Cindy...Thank you again for the guidance. As to the loop " And this loop ` Do Until objWord Is Nothing` makes absolutely NO sense" This is the only way I could find to close all open instances of Word. Since each file generated is an individual document, it will leave each one open on the desktop when done. This loop was being used to close all open Word instances. Is there a better way to accomplish the same task?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to sort all this... The basic steps (and there are lots of code samples "out there" that demonstrate) is: 1. Start the Word application. 2. Start the loop. 3. Open/create the document and do things to it (run mail merge). 4. Save *and close* the result (now the ActiveDocument). - **At this point** the main merge document is still open. You should not need to close it before using it again for a merge. So this line needs to come out of the loop ` objMMMD.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges`, also this one: `Set objMMMD = Nothing` *and* the `If`-block following...

Comment: ...Once the loop has finished, then close the main merge document and set it to nothing (those two lines now inside the loop - move them outside). Leave the two lines that quit and release the Word application. Comment out everything that follows, up to the MsgBox.

Comment: Thank you! That solved everything. Works like a charm! Also want to say thanks for the education...not an expert but striving to get as close as I can!